have something over someone
a) What do you have over Tom?
Could that mean

In what way are you better than Tom.

I think I can beat Tom tomorrow.
Really? What do you have over Tom? As far as I can see, he's better than you in every way.
Does that dialogue make sense?
It seems that 'have something over someone' could mean 'to be in a position to coerce someone because one knows something about that person'. I thought that was 'to have something on someone'.
Can the two expressions be used synonymously in the right context?
Many thanks

@MichaelHarvey: Idiomatically, having power / influence (often but not always, by virtue of knowing a secret) is more likely to be She's got something on him rather than ...something over him. There are dozens of matches in the first link (most of which reflect the context, I'm sure), but just three matches for the over version.

Your suggested dialogue makes sense only because context is so powerful. My ear skips right over the somewhat unusual use of "over" and assumes the meaning. This would be especially true if the dialogue were set somewhere other than my reality, like Tom Sawyer and his 19th-century slang; I'd just suppose it was "the way they talked."

In the absence of any context, I'd have to say your first assessment of the phrase is correct. To have something over someone else means you possess an advantage over them. In the context of a job interview, for example, that might mean you have a skill the other person does not.
To have something on somebody colloquially means you possess some information that could discredit them. This is very different. It is possible that the two phrases have become conflated.
One reason for possible conflation, as has been pointed out in comments, is that another unique specific phrase "to have a hold over someone" exists. This phrase means someone is controlling someone else. An example of this kind of control may be when someone uses damning information they "have on" the other person to bribe them, but there are certainly other ways this phrase is used, such as when a person has 'groomed' someone psychologically over time in order to exert control over them. It's worth noting that the phrase "to have a hold on" something also exists and similarly means you are in control, but not in a negative way - for example, you could have a hold on your finances meaning you are managing them well.
Another possible reason is that having something on someone could also be seen as having an advantage over them if used as a bribe, meaning that they also have something over them. In such a context, one is just a type of the other rather than something synonymous.

I don't know; in the absence of any context, I would assume the "have a hold over" meaning (and did, on first reading of the question). The comparison meaning is often phrased differently ("What does he have that I don't," or the literal "What do you have compared to Tom").
